# Ignore files without extension in ack

Tags: ack

I would like to define a file type that would enable me to ignore all files without extension in `ack`. In my `.ackrc` file I have added:

```
--type-set=csv:ext:csv,tsv
```

To handle CSV files that I often exclude from searches via `--nocsv` switch when running `ack` query. However, some of the files I would like to exclude have no CSV extension. Ideally, I would like to be able to arrive at a syntax:

```
ack --nocsv --nosansext searchStuff ~/SomeProjects
```

I would like for this command to:

- Exclude CSV files
- Exclude files without extension
- Include all other syntax files that I have in `SomeProjects` folder.

Is it possible to define a file type in `ack` to capture files without extension?

Comment: Try `--type-add 'csv:match:/^[^.]+$/'`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Thanks very much, it's a good suggestion. The command: `ack --nocsv --type-add 'csv:match:/^[^.]+$/' searchPhrase ~/` worked as desired, would you care to explain how the `'csv:match:/^[^.]+$/'` works?

Comment: There are 3 other types of filters beyond `ext`: `is`, `match`, and `firstlinematch`.  `is` and `match` match against filename, `firstlinematch` matches against the first line of the file.  So `--type-add 'csv:match:/^[^.]+$/'` adds files without extension to the `csv` type.  All straight from the manual, section "Defining your own types".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use find to create the list of the files you want to inspect:

```
find ~/SomeProjects -type f -regex '\./[^.]*$' | ack searchStuff -x
```

I have a version of ack that has no support for the csv filetype. You can see all supported types with `ack --help-types` and you can find all types in your directory with: `ack --show-types -f ~/SomeProjects`. I found many text files without type but with extension, for example: `.cfg`, `.md` or `.txt`.

Comment: Thanks very much, concerning the `csv` file, I've defined this type in `.ackrc`; my ambition was to add another type for files with no extension. In practical terms those are often CSV files that were saved like that in past, so I would like to exclude them as they get into results unnecessarily.